# SWT Equivalent of JPANEL

Tags: swt, jlabel

What's the equivalent of a `JPanel` in `SWT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original question asked for the `SWT` equivalent of a `JLabel`.

There's also an [org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CLabel.html).

The `SWT` equivalent of a `JPanel` is [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CLabel.html)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the [feature comparison table compiled by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/grid/library/os-swingswt/) (please see at the bottom of the page) detailing the relative options within AWT, Swing and SWT.

The equivalent of a JPanel in SWT is a [Composite](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html), [CLabel](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CLabel.html) or [Canvas](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Canvas.html) depending on what you want to achieve.
*NB: The eclipse SWT API is a bit temperamental.*

@Gilbert_Le_Blanc is correct if you want the JLabel properties. I recommend the feature comparison table to see just what it is that you need.

Comment: Feature comparison table is at the bottom of the linked page.